# Как развернуть gho на виртуальную машину под ubuntu?

Tags: virtualbox, ubuntu

Есть у меня система, завернутая нортоном в .gho файл. Я хочу восстановить эту систему на virtualbox. Как это сделать?Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

загрузить виртуальную машину с загрузочного диска norton ghost.восстановить также, как восстанавливали бы обычную комп.